# Why aren't live formulas filter-friendly?

Tags: excel-formula

I've been sending spreadsheets to a client that often contain live formulas (probably my first mistake). For some reason, when she tries filtering the data, the formulas get completely wonky and I end up redoing everything.

Case in point: 
This formula should have B4="Yes" and A4 in the SUMIF. Instead, after the filter, A18 appeared which references the wrong ID (which used to be in B4 prior to the filter).
=IF(B4="Yes","",IF(SUMIF('Rawdata'!D19:D617,A18,'Rawdata'!R19:S617)=0,"No","Yes"))

Any ideas on why this is the case? And how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain more about how you send her the sheet? Are you doing any copy and pasting?

Comment: Yes, the sum formula seemed to update (so if ID A2 was changed to A6 the sum would also be across 6s) but a nested IF(SUMIF) statement didn't update (it was still pulling from A2 even if the unique id moved to A6)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know if she didn't any copy and pasting - I didn't. What I sent to her had a variety of SUM and IF/SUMIF formulas that pulled from another sheet in the workbook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kelley, you're going to have to copy the entire table and paste values to send to the client. The reference points in the formulas change as the table is filtered according to the filtering. Making the entire table values only will also decrease the file size (added bonus).

My suggestion would be to send the client one tab with the live formulas if they want to see how you derived your results, and one 'formalized' tab with values pasted for further data analysis and manipulation by the client.

Let me know how this works for you.